# Classification of the Finite Abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, book-recommendation

I am studying "Abstract Algebra" by Gregory T. Lee. I am going through chapter 5, "Direct Products and the Classification of Finite Abelian Groups" at the moment, but it has been rather difficult for me. I would like to know if you know of any books, papers or online videos where this topic is discussed in detail and with examples, in order to understand a little better. Also, it would help me if you told me here what are the main ideas of this subject, what I should focus on to overcome it. In this book the subject is developed using p-groups. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I found Gallian's, *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra"* to be very clear on these topics. It comes with plenty of exercises, half of which with solutions.